# How to use evm compile?

Tags: solidity, evm, compilation

I have been testing with evm and I am not getting any output.

Code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract d8 {

    function myBalance() pure public returns (uint) {
        return 880;
    }

}
```

My asm is from here -

```
solc --asm d8.sol > d8.asm
```

Then I tried -

```
evm compile d8.asm
```

Not much happens (output is a blank line).

I tried various options and adding "run" at the end but nothing produced any output.

Has anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Solidity has an own workflow to deal with assembly. Refer to https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/assembly.html# and check the phases:

1. Assembly
2. Desugaring
3. Opcode Stream
4. Byte Stream

Output of phase 2 can be generated as follows:
    solc --asm

However, evm compile expects you to have phase 3.

e.g. check the code: https://github.com/IC3Hydra/Hydra/blob/master/submarine_sends/to_contract/clone_withdraw.easm

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you used `evm` in the right way. The `compiler` option is not for EVM assemble but for easm, the deprecated AST of Solidity. Relevant information is rather limited, and the only one I find is that evmlab mentions a little bit. Refer to my other [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/127185/73604) if you want more guides for the `evm`
command shipped with geth.

Comment: Needs to construct a better answer, explaining how things work and refrain from complaining about other users.